# Numpy sum elements of ndarray at specific positions of another ndarray (similar to np.put)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to accumulate the sum of a numpy array at specific positions of another numpy array without using any loop. This is similar to what [numpy.put](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.put.html#numpy.put) does, but I'd like to accumule the sum instead of replacing the elements.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros([2, 2])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
indices = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

Here, `np.put(a, indices, b)` gives the following result:

`a = [[ 5.  6.][ 2.  0.]]`

Instead, I'd like to obtain:

`a = [[ 9.  10.][ 2.  0.]]`

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.add.at`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros([2, 2])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> indices = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1]])
>>> 
>>> np.add.at(a.ravel(), indices.ravel(), b.ravel())
>>> a
array([[  9.,  10.],
       [  2.,   0.]])
>>>
```

an alternative, and in my experience often quite a bit faster is `np.bincount`:

```
>>> a = np.zeros([2, 2])
>>> a += np.bincount(indices.ravel(), b.ravel(), minlength=a.size).reshape(a.shape)
>>> a
array([[  9.,  10.],
       [  2.,   0.]])
>>>
```